# D3 plugin error

Tags: d3.js

I want to use D3 jquery plugin.

I need to create a line chart.

I use exactly the same CSS, JS and HTML this : https://codepen.io/beacrea/pen/reywxz

```
var margin = {
    top: 4,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 8,
    left: 4
  },
  width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 240 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale()
  .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
  .interpolate("basis")
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.date);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.trend);
  });

var svg = d3.select(".graph").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.tsv("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cbeas.misc/data.tsv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.trend = +d.trend;
  });

  x.domain([data[0].date, data[data.length - 1].date]);
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
    return d.trend;
  }));

  svg.append("linearGradient")
    .attr("id", "temperature-gradient")
    .attr("gradientUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
    .attr("x1", 0).attr("y1", y(0))
    .attr("x2", 0).attr("y2", y(100))
    .selectAll("stop")
    .data([{
      offset: "0%",
      color: "#2D6785"
    }, {
      offset: "25%",
      color: "#41A7E1"
    },{
      offset: "50%",
      color: "orange"
    }, {
      offset: "75%",
      color: "#EC9030"
    }, {
      offset: "100%",
      color: "#EC5B30"
    }])
    .enter().append("stop")
    .attr("offset", function(d) {
      return d.offset;
    })
    .attr("stop-color", function(d) {
      return d.color;
    });

  svg.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line);
});
```

But I have an console error : d3 is not defined. 
How can I define d3 ?
I added the d3.js script in my HTML file.

What do I have forgotten ?

UPDATE WITH HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr-FR">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Test</title>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/d3.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="graph"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you include the index.html where you have imported the script?

Comment: @echonax, Yes I updated the post

Comment: @Xroad  d3.js has nothing to do with jQuery (*it's not a plugin*). More importantly in your html  you only include the d3 library, but where is your code ?

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli, Ok so I don't need jquery with D3. I used : cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js

Comment: @Xroad can you update you html to show how you include the d3.js library and how you include/run your own code ?

Comment: Looks like you just haven't `called` your javascript.  Does this [plunker clarify](http://plnkr.co/edit/JbevpOEvf0whSTYsZ4yg?p=preview) how you should be doing that?  Look at line 17 in `index.html`.

Comment: @Mark, that's work ! It's cool thank you ! I would like to know how to create a second line chart please ?